# Why is a SQL query executing slower in PHP than in Query Analyzer

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query that takes 5 seconds to run in SQL Server Managment Studio, but it takes 33 seconds in PHP to run the same query using *$qid=db_query($countQuery);*
Has anyone got any idea why this might be?

We are using SQL Server 2000 which I do not believe is the problem.

[edit]
After doing some profiling we noticed that the execution plans were completely different between the analyzer and the query from PHP.  This was done on a single machine, web, sql and query analyzer.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you test from the same machine?

Comment: Are you running it against the same database? Has anybody added data to the database? Wouldn't it be that the Query Analyzer was running locally and the PHP script running remotely (so the data has to travel on the network)?

Comment: You are talking about the query only - no data was fetched into the PHP script?

Comment: I am running the website from a machine on our network which connects to an external database server.  The query was run from my machine to the same server.  The same problem is happening on our live website which has the website and database one the same server.  If you remote desktop to it and run the query it is 10 times faster than through PHP.

Comment: Presumably it is the connection to the remote Db that is taking the time. Of course if you connect to the Db server and run a query it will be faster.

Comment: Is the query using variables in the PHP and in the query analyzer? Sometimes substituting the variable with a value can cause changes to the execution plan.

Comment: The query is built into a string and then executed.  I only time the execution on the site.  There are no variables used anywhere in the query.
The really strange thing is that it only seems to have started this about a week ago...and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem...well, at least in this case.  The problem was the mssql_* that ships with PHP.  We tested the new sqlsrv_* which ran a 62 second query (mssql_) in 1.4 seconds so it is definitely much faster.

[edit]
The reason for it running slow in the mssql library was because of duplicate data in our table (which only had two id columns without any constraints on so we never noticed it).

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using parameters?
[Parameter sniffing can affect execution plans ...](http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is known to happen based on different session settings.  Like a different setting for [`set ansi_nulls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx), or a different login name.

Also, sometimes a connection plan is outdated, but still used for old connections. To see if that is the problem, clear the plan cache with:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Answer (score 0):

I had cases when the Sql login, under which I executed the query, made a difference in performance. When running the query as sysadmin from Query Analyzer, the query was faster than when the applicaiton ran it as a different sql user.

This might not solve your problem, but it's something which can be checked when running out of ideas.